# Secondary monitors not working in laptop after using without dock

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hp-elitebook

My problems started about the time when updating to Windows 1803:

Sometimes, after using the laptop without dock and connecting to the docking station the secondary displays only show the background image but don't show any windows I drag there. My mouse cursor shows up in all the displays but if I am dragging something the cursor doesn't show up on the secondary displays anymore either.

Specs:

- HP EliteBook 840 G3 with the latest updates (as far as I'm aware of)
- Windows 10 1809
- 2 external monitors, one is my primary display, secondary displays are the other external monitor and laptop's own display (connected via the docking station)
- Screen is extended between the monitors

Other symptoms:

- If I take a screenshot from the secondary display the windows not visible on the screen **do** show up in the screenshot.
- The taskbar might show up floating in the mid-screen and half shown windows might be visible in other displays
- All 3 monitors **are** detected by Windows but needless to say that if I click `Detect` the detecting number doesn't show up in the secondary monitors

Only known cure at the time is reboot (which always works though). Nearly everything has been tried: disconnect from the dock, change display settings, sleep - disconnect - wake etc.

Comment: Your laptop model should have a [DisplayPort](https://www.eizoglobal.com/library/healthcare/daisychain/index.html) on the right side

Comment: Yes it does and using it when the problem is "activated" seems to work just as poorly as using the monitors via the docking station: the monitor connected to the display port works fine but the laptop internal display doesn't update the contents properly anymore (cursor shows up but windows can't be dragged there - see symptoms above). When I disconnect the display port the laptop display starts to work again.

Comment: Did you try to update [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)?

Comment: Yes, the problem has surfaced now and then for some months now (maybe a year) even though latest Windows updates have always been installed.

Comment: If your laptop mounts Intel HD Graphics 520, there's a 2019 [driver](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-elitebook-840-g3-notebook-pc/7815294/swItemId/ob-225035-1). Good luck ....